# Python- Insert new values into 'nested' list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

What I'm trying to do isn't a huge problem in php, but I can't find much assistance for Python.

In simple terms, from a list which produces output as follows:

```
{"marketId":"1.130856098","totalAvailable":null,"isMarketDataDelayed":null,"lastMatchTime":null,"betDelay":0,"version":2576584033,"complete":true,"runnersVoidable":false,"totalMatched":null,"status":"OPEN","bspReconciled":false,"crossMatching":false,"inplay":false,"numberOfWinners":1,"numberOfRunners":10,"numberOfActiveRunners":8,"runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":2.8,"size":34.16},{"price":2.76,"size":200},{"price":2.5,"size":237.85}],"availableToLay":[{"price":2.94,"size":6.03},{"price":2.96,"size":10.82},{"price":3,"size":33.45}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832765}...
```

All I want to do is add in an extra field, containing the 'runner name' in the data set below, into each of the 'runners' sub lists from the initial data set, based on selection_id=selectionId.

So initially I iterate through the full dataset, and then create a separate list to get the runner name from the runner id (I should point out that runnerId===selectionId===selection_id, no idea why there are multiple names are used), this works fine and the code is shown below:

for market_book in market_books:

```
market_catalogues = trading.betting.list_market_catalogue(
    market_projection=["RUNNER_DESCRIPTION", "RUNNER_METADATA", "COMPETITION", "EVENT", "EVENT_TYPE", "MARKET_DESCRIPTION", "MARKET_START_TIME"],
    filter=betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(
        market_ids=[market_book.market_id],
    ),
    max_results=100)

data = []
for market_catalogue in market_catalogues:
    for runner in market_catalogue.runners:
        data.append(
            (runner.selection_id, runner.runner_name)
        )
```

So as you can see I have the data in data[], but what I need to do is add it to the initial data set, based on the selection_id.

I'm more comfortable with Php or Javascript, so apologies if this seems a bit simplistic, but the code snippets I've found on-line only seem to assist with very simple Python lists and nothing 'nested' (to me the structure seems similar to a nested array).

As per the request below, here is the full list:

```
{"marketId":"1.130856098","totalAvailable":null,"isMarketDataDelayed":null,"lastMatchTime":null,"betDelay":0,"version":2576584033,"complete":true,"runnersVoidable":false,"totalMatched":null,"status":"OPEN","bspReconciled":false,"crossMatching":false,"inplay":false,"numberOfWinners":1,"numberOfRunners":10,"numberOfActiveRunners":8,"runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":2.8,"size":34.16},{"price":2.76,"size":200},{"price":2.5,"size":237.85}],"availableToLay":[{"price":2.94,"size":6.03},{"price":2.96,"size":10.82},{"price":3,"size":33.45}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832765},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":20,"size":3},{"price":19.5,"size":26.36},{"price":19,"size":2}],"availableToLay":[{"price":21,"size":13},{"price":22,"size":2},{"price":23,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832767},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":11,"size":9.75},{"price":10.5,"size":3},{"price":10,"size":28.18}],"availableToLay":[{"price":11.5,"size":12},{"price":13.5,"size":2},{"price":14,"size":7.75}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832766},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":48,"size":2},{"price":46,"size":5},{"price":42,"size":5}],"availableToLay":[{"price":60,"size":7},{"price":70,"size":5},{"price":75,"size":10}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832769},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":18.5,"size":28.94},{"price":18,"size":5},{"price":17.5,"size":3}],"availableToLay":[{"price":21,"size":20},{"price":23,"size":2},{"price":24,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832768},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":4.3,"size":9},{"price":4.2,"size":257.98},{"price":4.1,"size":51.1}],"availableToLay":[{"price":4.4,"size":20.97},{"price":4.5,"size":30},{"price":4.6,"size":16}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832771},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":24,"size":6.75},{"price":23,"size":2},{"price":22,"size":2}],"availableToLay":[{"price":26,"size":2},{"price":27,"size":2},{"price":28,"size":2}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":12832770},{"status":"ACTIVE","ex":{"tradedVolume":[],"availableToBack":[{"price":5.7,"size":149.33},{"price":5.5,"size":29.41},{"price":5.4,"size":5}],"availableToLay":[{"price":6,"size":85},{"price":6.6,"size":5},{"price":6.8,"size":5}]},"sp":{"nearPrice":null,"farPrice":null,"backStakeTaken":[],"layLiabilityTaken":[],"actualSP":null},"adjustmentFactor":null,"removalDate":null,"lastPriceTraded":null,"handicap":0,"totalMatched":null,"selectionId":10064909}],"publishTime":1551612312125,"priceLadderDefinition":{"type":"CLASSIC"},"keyLineDescription":null,"marketDefinition":{"bspMarket":false,"turnInPlayEnabled":false,"persistenceEnabled":false,"marketBaseRate":5,"eventId":"28180290","eventTypeId":"2378961","numberOfWinners":1,"bettingType":"ODDS","marketType":"NONSPORT","marketTime":"2019-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","suspendTime":"2019-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","bspReconciled":false,"complete":true,"inPlay":false,"crossMatching":false,"runnersVoidable":false,"numberOfActiveRunners":8,"betDelay":0,"status":"OPEN","runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":1,"id":10064909},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":2,"id":12832765},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":3,"id":12832766},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":4,"id":12832767},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":5,"id":12832768},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":6,"id":12832770},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":7,"id":12832769},{"status":"ACTIVE","sortPriority":8,"id":12832771},{"status":"LOSER","sortPriority":9,"id":10317013},{"status":"LOSER","sortPriority":10,"id":10317010}],"regulators":["MR_INT"],"countryCode":"GB","discountAllowed":true,"timezone":"Europe\/London","openDate":"2019-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","version":2576584033,"priceLadderDefinition":{"type":"CLASSIC"}}}
```

Comment: the dictionary is extreamly hard to read, could you only print the relevant "runners" part? or atleast format it better?

Comment: The dict is not valid. I put it through the linter and there is many errors.

Comment: In really simplistic terms its basically this:

market_book = {"marketId":"1.130856098",....,"runners":[{"status":"ACTIVE",...."selectionId":12832765}...

and I would like to add in another field to the 'runners' sub-list called 'runner_name' by matching the selection_id from my other dataset to selectionId from the runners sub-list in the larger initial dataset.

Does that help clarify or have I made it more confusing?

Comment: The dict is truncated in an attempt to make it easier to read, it does work correctly, however its massive, so I tried to only capture a piece of the relevant part.

In short though, I'm not sure most of it matters, as all I need to do is insert one field into the sub-list, it could be a really simple data structure and the process would be the same (I presume), so I'm presuming its my lack of Python experience here thats the problem (as the full dict appears fine, I am able to extract from it, convert to JSON etc)

Comment: dont truncate it, we need to to feed it to python, its completely unreadable in its current form, please edit your question

Comment: Full list added, as requested, but it may be a bit tricky to read as its huge!

Comment: assuming you loaded your have your json as a python object, you can access selectionid with `parsed_jason['runners'][i]['selectionId']` where `i` is an index. i would give you a full answer but i have no idea where you are getting `runner_name` from, its not in the data you gave us

Comment: runner name is in the original post (2nd code snippet), that is the field I'm trying to add to the dataset.

I have no issues accessing a field from the dataset, I have an issue trying to add the runner name field into it, thats the problem (for clarity).

Comment: But to simplify, essentially that 2nd code snippet simply ends up with a list called data, which has 2 fields, runner_name and selection_id. All I am trying to do is add runner_name to the original dataset, based on selection_id = selectionId.

It should be really simple, but I'm being a bit dumb I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, essentially this works...with one exception...I can see from the print(...) in the loop that the attribute is updated, however what I can't seem to do is then see this update outside the loop.

```
mkt_runners = []
for market_catalogue in market_catalogues:
    for r in market_catalogue.runners:
        mkt_runners.append((r.selection_id, r.runner_name))

for market_book in market_books:
    for runner in market_book.runners:
        for x in mkt_runners:
            if runner.selection_id in x:
                setattr(runner, 'x', x[1])
                print(market_book.market_id, runner.x, runner.selection_id)

print(market_book.json())
```

So the print(market_book.market_id.... displays as expected, but when I print the whole list it shows the un-updated version. I can't seem to find an obvious solution, which is odd, as it seems like a really simple thing (I tried messing around with indents, in case that was the problem, but it doesn't seem to be, its like its not refreshing the market_book list post update of the runners sub list)!

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered and then re-submit a new question and the last bit is perhaps slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

i think i understand what you are trying to do now

first hold your data as a python object (you gave us a json object)

```
import json
my_data = json.loads(my_json_string)

for item in my_data['runners']:
    item['selectionId'] = [item['selectionId'], my_name_here]
```

the thing is that `my_data['runners'][i]['selectionId']` is a string, unless you want to concat the name and the id together, you should turn it into a list or even a dictionary
each `item` is a dicitonary so you can always also a new keys to it

```
item['new_key'] = my_value
```

Comment: Thank you, that does appear logical...however I have no control over how I receive the initial dataset, when I try the above, I get the following:

    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Which suggests it is a python list, rather than a JSON object (I think), which is a bit confusing!

Comment: where do you get this error? here `my_data = json.loads(my_json_string)`? what is your `my_json_string` here? is it already a python object at this point?

Comment: yes correct, at that line.

From the error, I assumed it was already a python object at this point (if I check with type it suggests thats the case).

Comment: I'm still plugging away with this and getting nowhere, I get your logic and I can't see why it wouldn't work, but I keep getting:

'object does not support item assignment'

Comment: could you show me some of your code? where do you get object does not support item assignment? can you tell me what the output of `type(you_object)` is?

Comment: Ah apologies I may have been a bit dumb!

This works:

    for market_book in market_books:
        for runner in market_book.runners:
            setattr(runner, 'x', 5)
            print(runner.x)

            print(market_book.json())

However I'm still struggling to iterate through my other list and return the correct values based on selectionid, if I use your syntax I get that error, but am I correct in thinking your syntax above possibly is erroneous (apologies if not), i.e.

for item in my_data['runners']:
    item['selectionId'] = [item['selectionId'], my_name_here]

Comment: the type may be a bit meaningless as its a custom class that I am unable to edit unfortunately (but essentially its a list).

Comment: `for item in my_data['runners']:
    item['selectionId'] = [item['selectionId'], my_name_here]`

Comment: Sorry the formatting was poor previously! The above was your code snippet, and below is my code that works (but only using static data):

```for market_book in market_books: for runner in market_book.runners: setattr(runner, 'x', 5) print(runner.x) print(market_book.json())```

Comment: Okay, I think I'm up to speed now, so the problem I'm facing is exactly what you initially mentioned, where you said:

```my_data['runners'][i]['selectionId']```

Is a string...now I can't change how I receive that, but is there anyway I can convert somehow from a string to a list / dict?

Comment: @always_confused does `my_data['runners'][i]['selectionId'] = [my_data['runners'][i]['selectionId'], 'something_else']`  not work? if it doesnt, what error does it give you?

Comment: I think I might be mis-understanding the syntax here. What should 'something_else' be, the second list?

For the above (if I understand it correctly) I get:

```TypeError: 'MarketBook' object is not subscriptable
```

(MarketBook is a custom class, which in this case = my_data)

Comment: ahh, this works:

`mkt_runners = []
    for market_catalogue in market_catalogues:
        for r in market_catalogue.runners:
            mkt_runners.append((r.selection_id, r.runner_name))

    for market_book in market_books:
        for runner in market_book.runners:
            for x in mkt_runners:
                if runner.selection_id in x:
                    print(market_book.market_id, runner.selection_id, x[1])`

I still have to work out how to get it back into market_book.runners[i]runner. But given the structure that may take a while!!